# How to fix 'Managed SQL Server Installer has stopped working'

Tags: sql-server-2008, installation

I am trying to install SQL Server 2008 Enterprise Edition on Windows Server 2008. I have done all the process till the Installation correctly. However, the installer displays the message "***Managed SQL Server Installer has stopped working***".

No online Solution has been provided yet....

Anyone sorted this problem before?

Answer (score 1):

This is usually a problem with your installation of .NET framework. E.g:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/34671131-a095-4068-b4d8-ab5ef6f5b8cc/managed-sql-server-installer-has-stopped-working

Check that your installations are all in working order by using the tools on this site:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/10/13/8999004.aspx

You may have to re-install any or all of your .NET framework versions.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying several methods that have not been approved, it is better to repair the MSSQL Server installation. On the other hand, there is some other issues that can be encountered during the repair process i.e. Installing the .NET Framework 3.5 on Windows 8, Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 as shown below.

[image]

In this case, if you have trouble during .NET Framework installation, you can install it by following the steps below (requires Windows 8, 8.1 or 10) setup disc or ISO file):

**1)** First you'll need to copy Windows 8 setup files to your hard disk. If you have Windows 8 setup ISO copied in your system, you can mount it by right-click on it and select "Mount" option or you can extract its content using 7-Zip.

If you have Windows 8 setup disc and don't want to copy its content, its ok. Just insert the disc in your CD/DVD drive so that Windows can access its content.

**2)** Now open Command Prompt as Administrator as mentioned here and then provide following command:

Dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx3 /All /Source:F:\sources\sxs /LimitAccess

Here "F:" represents the CD/DVD drive letter in your system which contains Windows 8 setup disc. Replace it with the correct drive letter according to your system.

If you extracted Windows 8 setup files in a directory, replace F:\sources\sxs with the correct path.

**3)** As soon as you execute the above mentioned command, Windows will start installing .NET Framework 3.5 in your system and it'll not require Internet connection.

[image]

It'll take a few minutes and you'll get a message that the operation completed successfully.

**4)** That's it. Now you have installed .NET Framework 3.5 in Windows 8 without using Internet connection.

For more information have a look at [How to Install Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 Offline in Windows 8 and Later without Internet Connection?](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-install-microsoft-net-framework-3-5-offline-in-windows-8-without-internet-connection/). Hope this helps...